# Changing what is shown on a text panel

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a C# script for unity to create dialogue using 'Ink.Runtime' and this procedure in the code is attempting to switch the text to a new line when the condition is met. But when I attempt to run the script the following error is displayed:

Assets\C# Scripts\DialogueManager.cs(60,13): error CS0103: The name 'dialogueText' does not exist in the current context

Here's the relevant string of code written below

```
private void ContinueStory()
    {
        if (currentStory.canContinue)
        {
            dialogueText.text = currentStory.Continue();
        }
        else
        {
            ExitDialogueMode();
        }
    }
```

I think an issue may be that I was previously using the new input system but switched back to the old one and may have forgotten to change this string in using that input system. I'm relatively new to programming in C# and so help would be much appriciated!

Comment: The error is exactly what's said, you did not create/declare a variable called `dialogueText`; How are you assigning/creating `dialogueText` currently? How are you referrencing it?

Comment: its a text file in the actual unity project, not part of the c# script

Answer (score 0):

It's tough from the small snippet provided but from the error it looks like the assignment is outside the context of where your dialogText is accessible. Look at your modifier on how you instantiated the dialogText object and either change it to internal or public or pass the object in the method so it is within the context you are trying to change it.